# User is AUTHENTICATED, but: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'path'" error coming up

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, angularfire

**I've already implemented authentication in my app, and am having no problem with creating a user and authenticating.** However, now I am trying to upload a file to Firebase Storage, but it will only work when I remove the auth rule and make access public. If I leave the default rules to only allow authenticated users to access (which is what I want), I get the error: `Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'profile-image/test.PNG'.` I called a method to verify my auth state right before the put request, and I can read/write to the firestore database with no issues, so I know for sure I'm authenticated.

I'm a complete FNG so there's a good chance the problem is something silly that I've done/not done.  I'm using Angular if that is relevant.  I also activated a billing account with Google Cloud Platform, but that didn't make a difference.

Here's my console log showing the reference I used, the file I'm attempting to add (which again, both of those work just fine when I make access public), my uid from the auth state call, and then the error:

```
STARTING UPLOAD SERVICE                        upload.service.ts:26
FIREBASE STORAGE REFERENCE:                    upload.service.ts:27 
Reference {authWrapper: AuthWrapper, location: Location}
  authWrapper: AuthWrapper {bucket_: "my-app.appspot.com", deleted_: false, app_: FirebaseAppImpl, storageRefMaker_: ƒ, requestMaker_: ƒ, …}
bucket: (...)
fullPath: (...)
location: Location {bucket: "my-app.appspot.com", path_: "profile-image/test.PNG"}
name: (...)
parent: (...)
root: (...)
storage: (...)
__proto__: Object
                                                 upload.service.ts:28 
FILE CONTENTS:
                                                 upload.service.ts:29 
File(286831) {name: "test.PNG", lastModified: 1542480795011, lastModifiedDate: Sat Nov 17 2018 13:53:15 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 286831, …}
                                                 upload.service.ts:24 
USER AUTHENTICATED: Er6sWsDvEjM69WBAKxQffcbdPZG2
POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{my-app-name}/o?name=profile-image%2Ftest.PNG 403
                                                 upload.service.ts:33  
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/unauthorized", message_: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'profile-image/test.PNG'.", 
serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    "message": "Pe…n denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}
code: (...)
code_: "storage/unauthorized"
message: (...)
message_: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'profile-image/test.PNG'."
name: (...)
name_: "FirebaseError"
serverResponse: (...)
serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}"
__proto__: Object
```

Firebase Storage Rules

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/my-app.appspot.com/o {
  match /{allPaths=**} {
   allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

(I also tried request.auth.uid != null but that didn't make a difference.)

My upload service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  pushUpload(uploadFile: File) {
    console.log("STARTING UPLOAD SERVICE")
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    var storageRef = storage.ref();
    var profileRef = storageRef.child('profile-image');
    var docRef = profileRef.child(uploadFile.name);

    this.authService.getAuthState().subscribe(auth => {
      console.log("USER AUTHENTICATED: " + auth.uid);
    })
    console.log("FIREBASE STORAGE REFERENCE:")
    console.log(docRef);
    console.log("FILE CONTENTS:");
    console.log(uploadFile);
    docRef.put(uploadFile).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Firebase config in environment.ts:

```
import * as fb from 'firebase/app';

// This file can be replaced during build by using the `fileReplacements` array.
// `ng build --prod` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.
// The list of file replacements can be found in `angular.json`.

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "{my-api-key}",
    authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "my-app.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my-app",
    storageBucket: "gs://my-app.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "####"
  }
};

fb.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
```

I replaced some of the identifying information with generic in the console log & environment.ts file.
I should also mention that authentication was working just fine for me before I added `fb.initializeApp(environment.firebase);` but I was getting an error without this line once I tried to make an upload request.

Thanks so much in advance for any advice you may have & if I should provide any more info, please let me know!

Comment: Can whether or not the auth user's email is verified make a difference in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it did matter that I was using Angular.  I needed to add `AngularFireStorage` to my `app.module.ts` like so:

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage'; 

@NgModule({
....
providers: [..., AngularFireStorage]
```

and then also had to import to my uploads.component.ts:

```
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage';
```

and then I completely scrapped my UploadService and snagged parts of this guy's tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firebase-storage-with-angularfire-dropzone-file-uploader/  which uses an AngularFireUploadTask and some Observables to accomplish the entire upload process really easily.  So here's the resulting method I ended up with in my uploads.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploads',
  templateUrl: './uploads.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploads.component.css']
})
export class UploadsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() uploadFolder: string;  //the folder to save this particular upload to in the Storage Bucket   
  selectedFile: File;
  task: AngularFireUploadTask;  // Main task 
  percentage: Observable<number>;  // Progress monitoring
  snapshot: Observable<any>;// Progress monitoring


  constructor(
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  .
  .
  .

  startUpload() {  
    if (this.selectedFile.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') { 
      console.error('unsupported file type :( ')
      return;
    } else {
      const path = this.uploadFolder + "/" + this.userID;
      // The main task
      this.task = this.storage.upload(path, this.selectedFile)
      // Progress monitoring
      this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
      this.percentage.subscribe(data => {
        // Do something with my progress
      })
      this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();
      this.snapshot.subscribe(data => {
        // Do something with my progress
      })
      // The file's download URL
      this.task.then(snapshot => {
        console.log("UPLOAD SUCCESS!");
        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          console.log(url);
          //Do something with my new file's url
        })
      }, 
      (err) => {
        //Do something about errors...  
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And I removed the firebase initialization from my `environment.ts` file, so clearly Angular is initializing firebase for me somewhere since this is unnecessary.  I believe this is why there was a discrepancy between why Firestore showed I was authenticated (because I initialized firebase for logging in and firestore through AngularFire), but Firebase Storage showed I was NOT authenticated (because I initialized firebase for THAT separately in my `environment.ts` file, which was my work-around for not utilizing AngularFireStorage like I should have).  So basically this all boils down to the fact that I didn't(don't) fully understand what exactly Angular was doing for me.  ugh...I really hope this helps someone at some point...

Answer (score 4):

`allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

means, you have to login before being able to write there.

just try once with `==` and you'll see it works.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond, but as I explained in my post I am already logged in with Firebase Auth.  I blame myself for being so wordy nobody wants to read my post....this is why I can't use Twitter! -_-

Comment: have you tried changing the security rule for a test?

Comment: Well, I took the rule off entirely (simply left it as allow read, write;) to make it "public" access, which is basically the same thing.  I want the auth rule to remain in place, as I only want authenticated users to have access. My problem is that I AM authenticated, and it won't work with the auth rule in place.  Please see where I call my auth service right before the put request just to be sure.  If this does NOT confirm that I am indeed logged in, please let me know, because everything I am seeing tells me that I am authenticated properly, but Firebase Storage is acting like I am not.

Comment: And also, note how my console log shows where I confirmed my auth state by printing the auth.uid.  Please, what in the world am I missing here??

Comment: But just to be clear, of course I did try your suggestion, and it did allow me to make the upload.  But how can that be if I am in fact authenticated?

Comment: @Kat the problem is, that `my-app.appspot.com` is not a bucket name.

Comment: I replaced my app name with my-app for privacy reasons.  I got this bucket name from my Firebase console > Storage > Files and then at the top of the list of files.  If my bucket name is incorrect, then how could I add files when I remove the authentication rule?

Comment: you've missed the leading `gs://` protocol handler for the bucket.

Comment: Can you please recommend a method I could use to better check my authentication status?

Comment: Hmm, I see where it doesn't include that in the error message, but it is included in my environment.ts file that has the firebase config.  Is there somewhere else I need to put it?

Comment: Could I possibly be initializing firebase twice without "knowing" it?  I was able to log in and make reads/writes to the database (which also has auth rules) before I started trying to figure out how to upload to storage.  But if I take `fb.initializeApp(environment.firebase);` out of my environment.ts file, I can NOT upload to storage (even with the auth rule off), but I CAN still log in and read/write to the database.

Comment: I found in my app.module.ts file under imports: `
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, "my-app"),` could this be my problem????  If I remove it, nothing works.  Sorry if this is completely irrelevant, I don't even know what I don't know...

Comment: adding gs:// might be non-sense, but removing the .appspot.com should result in a bucket name.

Comment: Ok, I removed the .appspot.com from the end, but get this error: "Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response."

Comment: I also tried again after removing the auth rules, and same error so I don't think that's it.

Comment: I need to figure out why Firebase Storage thinks that I am not authenticated, but FirebaseAuth and Firestore think that I am.

Comment: Oh, also, the component that I am currently working in has an AuthGuard on it!

Answer (score 0):

For Angular application when you use:

`const storage = firebase.storage();`

It initializes storage for [DEFAULTE] application that certainly does not include authorization data (already logged user) to storage request.
it could be resolved without using `AngularFireStorage` (for me it was requirement to using  `listAll()` method  for backet path ref that are not supported in `AngularFireStorage`).
There is workaround how initialize fire storage with correct application that contains authorization user data:

```
    const apps = firebase.apps;         
    const app = apps && apps.find(x => x.name != '[DEFAULT]');
    const storage = firebase.storage(app);
```

Everything above  means you already update your rules for storage

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same error because I was trying to replace/override an existing file with a newer version but using the existing file "key". The solution was to delete the old file first then upload the new version.

```
onUploadImageBtnClicked(event, item) {
    this.afStorage.storage.ref('images/' + item.key).getDownloadURL()
        .then( url => {

            this.replaceExistingImage(event, item);

        }).catch( err => {

            if (err.code === 'storage/object-not-found') {

                this.uploadImage(event, item);

            }

        });
}

replaceExistingImage(event, item) {
    const sub = this.afStorage.ref('images/' + item.key)
        .delete().subscribe( () => {

            sub.unsubscribe();
            this.uploadImage(event, item);

        });
}

uploadImage(event, item) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    let fileRef;

    if (this.uploadImageSubscription) {
        this.uploadImageSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.uploadImageSubscription = this.afStorage.upload('images/' + item.key, files[0])
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                fileRef.ref.getDownloadURL().then( url => {

                    this.db.database.ref('items/' + item.key)
                        .update({
                            imageUrl: url

                        });

                });
            })
        ).subscribe( file => { fileRef = file; });
}
```