# Firebase insufficient permissions for .doc().get()

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

I am trying to authenticate a user in my app. I have a login screen that takes an email and password and then runs this:

```
login2(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const signInObs: Observable<UserCredential> = from(this.fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
    
    return signInObs.pipe(take(1), catchError(this.handleError), mergeMap((result: UserCredential) => {
        console.log(`done this ONE... ${result.user.uid}`);
        
        return this.firestore.collection('users').doc(result.user.uid).get().pipe(catchError(this.handleError), mergeMap((doc: DocumentSnapshot<any>) => {
            console.log(`done this two... ${doc.data().name}`);
            
            return result.user.getIdTokenResult(true).then((token: IdTokenResult) => {
                // authenticate the user in the code
                console.log(`done this three.. ${token.claims.admin}`);
                                    
                this.handleAuthentication(
                    result.user.email, 
                    result.user.uid,
                    doc.data().name,
                    token.claims.admin,
                    token.token 
                );
            }).catch(error => {
                throw new Error(error);
            });
        })); 
    }));
}
```

But the old `ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` error happens with respect to the  `this.firebase.collection('users').doc(result.user.uid).get()` part. This is all works just fine without that section - i.e. it logs in, gives me a token and so on. Everything works fine except it wont allow me to access that user record...

The rules in my database are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // match logged in user doc in users collection
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    // match docs in the users collection
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

In reference to a reply that suggested it might be that FireAuth and Firestore modules aren't communicating correctly, this is how the `app.module` looks. These are all the references to the angular fire module in the app.module.

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // just components
  ],
  imports: [
    // other imports 
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule, 
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true}, 
        AuthenticationService,
        AngularFireFunctions
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And the constructor in the Authentication service:

```
constructor(private fAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
            private firestore: AngularFirestore,
            private router: Router) {
            }
```

I have tried running the id through the emulator and it seems like it should work. I have logged the userid from the login and it's identical to the document name it should be seeking.

This all seems like it should work but it doesn't. I have read a bunch of tutorials and none do anything hugely different - and differents are inconsistent between the tutorials.

I recognize the code isn't perfect in how it's written yet but wanted to make it functional first.

My data structure in the database looks like this:

[image: Data structure]

The ID of the documents is the user id of the relevant person, I double-checked they all are correct.

Double-checking it works otherwise if I allow universal read-write then everything works just fine... it's only when those rules come in that they don't work.

Comment: Please add how you are initializing `fAuth` and `firebase`. In this case, it also seems that `firebase`  is not the `firebase` SDK but a Firestore instance - you should rename this to something else like `firestore`, `db`, etc.. By convention, you should consider the variable name of `"firebase"`  to be reserved - treat it like `undefined` where you don't reassign it to anything else.

Comment: Just in the constructor: constructor(private fAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
                private firebase: AngularFirestore,
                private router: Router) {}... db is a service name in my app but maybe within that privately it might be good to rename, thanks.

Comment: While that just tells me how they are passed into your component, it doesn't cover where and how you are initializing them. I'm looking for where you are using `initializeApp()` and so on.

Comment: Oh, thats in my app module file: ``imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
  ]``. The config parameters are taken from the project but ill double check them now... (edit: all looks good, the firebaseConfig is in the right place and is the same details as what is on the firebase console).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify which document you want to match, in this case it is all documents(recursively). Here is the rule:

```
  rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // match logged in user doc in users collection
    match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    // match docs in the users collection
    match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT after comment:** According to the https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#version-2 *"In version 2 of the security rules, recursive wildcards match zero or more path items. match/cities/{city}/{document=**} matches documents in any subcollections as well as documents in the cities collection."*. I guess that the code above solves the subcollection problem. If you still encounter problems, kindly share your data structure so that people can help better.

**SECOND EDIT:** I guess the problem occurs because request.auth is null. Firebase will throw error if there is null pointer.So before request.auth.uid, you must check if request.auth is null or not. Like that:

```
  rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // match logged in user doc in users collection
    match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    // match docs in the users collection
    match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**THIRD EDIT:** I faced the same issue yesterday (rules are fine, and it works when all rules are set to true) but it was happening on mobile devices only, strangely. I found this issue on GitHub after searching: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2838. The problem was caused by the Firebase version. My version was 8.6.2 so I downgraded it to 8.6.1, and the problem was gone. You can downgrade it by:

```
npm install firebase@8.6.1
```

I think this is a very serious issue for Firebase, it holds people from developing and maintaining projects with Firebase backend. I hope this solves your issue too.

Comment: Same issue I am afraid - though the sub folder of the document is a collection so the document=** might not address anything in the DB.

Comment: Hi Ayse, thanks, I added the data structure to the main post. Is there a way that you know of I can check on the payload being sent to firebase? Maybe that will help diagnose the problem...

Comment: Hey, I continue to appreciate the help but its the same issue. Logging in works perfectly except when I try to read from the database, so the .doc() is what's causing the problems still. Same error message :/

I also think request.auth should not be null if there is a user logged in...

Comment: The login is definitively asynchronous - do you *know* that the auth has actually been completed before your .get()?  This is where it's useful to use the auth listeners.  Simply requesting the auth [this.fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)] is insufficient; the actual authorization is ANSYNCHRONOUS to this.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work, now I try again and it does. Even to be sure I changed back to the newer version and it broke again, then back to 8.6.1 and it worked again. Thanks so much, bounty awarded!!! Will update the main post in a bit with the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a less-Angular approach because you have a strange chain of `Observable` objects but each operation is being done only once. So instead of converting each step to an `Observable` and chaining them, we'll use and return the native `Promise` chain, which you can convert to an `Observable` later.

In addition, collecting a user's token and a snapshot of their user data can be done at the same time as they don't depend on each other. You also don't need to force refresh the user's ID token as it was already refreshed as part of the previous sign in step.

**Note:** Using `firebase` as the variable name of an instance of `AngularFirestore` is discouraged. `firebase` should be considered reserved for the Firebase Client SDK itself to prevent confusion. So in this code sample, I've renamed it to `firestore` although you could also use `db` or some other name.

```
login2(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            const userDocRef = this.firestore
                .collection('users')
                .doc(result.user.uid);

            return Promise.all([
                Promise.resolve(result.user),    // User object
                result.user.getIdTokenResult(),  // User's decoded ID token
                userDocRef.ref.get()             // User data in Firestore (from the wrapped Firebase SDK DocumentReference)
            ]);
        })
        .then(([user, tokenData, userDataSnapshot]) => {
            this.handleAuthentication( // <-- if this is a Promise, return it
                user.email, 
                user.uid,
                userDataSnapshot.get('name'), // <- more efficient than snap.data().name
                tokenData.claims.admin,
                tokenData.token
            );
        });
}
```

To convert to an `Observable` you'd use:

```
login2(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const signInPromise = /* ... code from above ... */

    return from(signInPromise);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but again its the same issue - I get the authentication issue ``ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`` . I do like your way of performing the login however, much cleaner, and thanks for the naming convention tip, I have changed that in the code now. My auth rules are still ``match /users/{userId}} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }``

Comment: Also the compiler doesnt like ``userDataSnapshot.get('name')`` or ``userDataSnapshot.data().name`` - am I missing something with that type I needed to include at another point?

Comment: Ah that's my bad for typing this by hand, I now see [AngularFire overloaded](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/3e991a61a8d27047e380593e66bea0089e739153/src/firestore/document/document.ts#L99-L106) the native Firebase SDK's `get()` with an `Observable`-returning method. We can bypass that using `userDocRef.ref.get()` to pull out the native `Promise`-returning method.

Comment: @Bogomip If this code is still not working, the problem is probably caused by `AngularFirestore` and `AngularFireAuth` being initialized as two independent Firestore apps. This would mean that while you have signed in on the app instance used by `fAuth`, the app instance used by `firestore`  hasn't been authenticated. You'll need to include how you are setting & initializing these in your question.

Comment: thanks, I am still learning the types in AngularFirestore, that was helpful. I added my ``app.module`` code to the bottom of my post. Thats the only place its initialized. I dont pass any authentication between the ``AngularFirestore`` and ``AngularFireAuth`` modules...

Comment: I think you might be onto something though, as I started looking up this issue and came across this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355433/user-is-authenticated-but-firebase-storage-user-does-not-have-permission-to) which is the same issue but with AngularFireStorage as opposed to AngularFirestore... so maybe the authentication happens but the firestore module doesn't know about it, they aren't communicating properly because of the setup...

Comment: So I have tried all the combinations in the app.module in terms of adding modules to the imports  and providers but no change. I also looked up a bunch of auth tutorials and none of them seem to require any crossover between the Auth and Firebase modules. It might be that I have to rework the module to use the onAuthChange function or whatever, but im just not sure why unless the loginWithUsernameAnbdPassword function just doesnt actually pass back the auth information but only authenticates on the server.

Comment: @Bogomip can you collect all the relevant files (remove everything unrelated, but so it still runs, like a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) into a ZIP file (package.json, AppModule, the Component/Service with login, and so on) sent to [my email](https://stcm.dev), so I can take a look. Ideally I should be able to run `npm install` and then start running it straight away.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading Firebase to 8.6.1 as I stated in my answer? I believe this might be the isssue.

Answer (score 1):

The login is definitively asynchronous - do you *know* that the auth has actually been completed before your .get()?  This is where it's useful to use the auth listeners.  Simply requesting the auth [this.fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)] is insufficient; the actual authorization is ANSYNCHRONOUS to this.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

I use a series of asynchronous calls and listeners to login/logout - I'm building *some* of it into a library, but the listeners and state changes required are out-of-scope for the library.

Comment: Hi LeadDreamer, im pretty confident because if I make authentication open to all it works fine - it only doesn't work if I have the rules on the database. I have updated the code in the main post so you can see the most up to date version...

Comment: Hi again, actually now seeing that if I set all rules to if request.auth.uid != null it still doesnt work, so perhaps it is an async issue... ill try separating it all out to see if that works better.